# Chnage or Update the route at run time in Veins SUMO in xml file

Tags: xml, veins, sumo

Please tell me any one knows about that How to update or change the route file at runtime in veins SUMO?

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in changing the file once the simulation is running but you can give new routes to your vehicles for instance by using the changeVehicleRoute command in TraCICommandInterface::Vehicle.